# npm audit fix --force is not fixing any problems

Tags: node.js, npm

I've deleted the package-lock.json and node_modules. Then npm i. No success. Tried the same but with yarn install instead. Nothing. I reinstalled NodeJS. Also no success.
npm is at version 7.12.1 npm audit fix does not do a damn thing. How can I fix this? please who knows solution reply here to solve my problem thank you

````
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.4: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.

added 1943 packages, and audited 1944 packages in 8m

71 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

105 vulnerabilities (24 low, 71 moderate, 10 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
PS F:\React-Webapps\onevaxin> npm audit fix
npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.5 node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/ini
npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.5 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.5 fsevents@1.2.4 at node_modules/fsevents
npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.5 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix ini@1.3.5 Check for updates to the fsevents package.      
npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/minimist
npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 fsevents@1.2.4 at node_modules/fsevents
npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@0.0.8 Check for updates to the fsevents package.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rc/node_modules/minimist
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 fsevents@1.2.4 at node_modules/fsevents
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix minimist@1.2.0 Check for updates to the fsevents package.
npm WARN audit fix tar@4.4.1 node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/tar
npm WARN audit fix tar@4.4.1 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix tar@4.4.1 fsevents@1.2.4 at node_modules/fsevents
npm WARN audit fix tar@4.4.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix tar@4.4.1 Check for updates to the fsevents package.
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/mkdirp
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 is a bundled dependency of
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 fsevents@1.2.4 at node_modules/fsevents
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 It cannot be fixed automatically.
npm WARN audit fix mkdirp@0.5.1 Check for updates to the fsevents package.

added 13 packages, changed 5 packages, and audited 1957 packages in 1m

71 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

# npm audit report

braces  <2.3.1
Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/786
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@4.0.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/braces
  micromatch  0.2.0 - 2.3.11
  Depends on vulnerable versions of braces
  node_modules/micromatch
    jest-cli  12.1.1-alpha.2935e14d || 12.1.2-alpha.6230044c - 24.8.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-config
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-snapshot
    Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
    Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
    node_modules/jest-cli
      jest  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.4 || 23.4.0 - 23.6.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-cli
      node_modules/jest
        react-scripts  >=0.3.0-alpha
        Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest
        Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-flexbugs-fixes
        Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-safe-parser
        Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
        Depends on vulnerable versions of terser-webpack-plugin
        Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
        node_modules/react-scripts
    jest-config  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 24.0.0-alpha.16
    Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-jasmine2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
    Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
    node_modules/jest-config
      jest-runner  21.0.0-alpha.1 - 22.4.4 || 23.4.0 - 23.6.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-config
      Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
      node_modules/jest-runner
      jest-runtime  12.1.1-alpha.2935e14d - 24.8.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-plugin-istanbul
      Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-config
      Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
      Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
      Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
      Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
      Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
      node_modules/jest-runtime
    jest-haste-map  16.1.0-alpha.691b0e22 - 24.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
    Depends on vulnerable versions of sane
    node_modules/jest-haste-map
    jest-message-util  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 23.1.0 || 23.4.0 - 24.0.0-alpha.16
    Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
    node_modules/jest-message-util
      expect  21.0.0-beta.1 - 22.4.3 || 23.4.0 - 23.6.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
      node_modules/expect
        jest-jasmine2  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.4 || 23.4.0 - 23.6.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of expect
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-snapshot
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
        node_modules/jest-jasmine2
      jest-snapshot  23.4.0 - 23.6.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
      node_modules/jest-snapshot
        jest-resolve-dependencies  23.4.0 - 23.6.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-snapshot
        node_modules/jest-resolve-dependencies
      jest-util  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.3 || 23.4.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
      node_modules/jest-util
        jest-environment-jsdom  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.3 || 23.4.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
        node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom
        jest-environment-node  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.3 || 23.4.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
        node_modules/jest-environment-node
    test-exclude  <=4.2.3
    Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
    node_modules/test-exclude
      babel-plugin-istanbul  <=5.0.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of test-exclude
      node_modules/babel-plugin-istanbul
        babel-jest  14.2.0-alpha.ca8bfb6e - 24.0.0-alpha.16
        Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-plugin-istanbul
        node_modules/babel-jest

immer  <8.0.1
Severity: high
Prototype Pollution - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1603
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@4.0.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/immer
  react-dev-utils  6.0.6-next.9b4009d7 - 11.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of immer
  node_modules/react-dev-utils
    react-scripts  >=0.3.0-alpha
    Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-flexbugs-fixes
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-safe-parser
    Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of terser-webpack-plugin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
    node_modules/react-scripts

ini  <1.3.6
Prototype Pollution - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1589
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/ini

merge  <2.1.1
Severity: high
Prototype Pollution - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1666
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@4.0.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/merge
  exec-sh  <=0.3.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of merge
  node_modules/exec-sh
    sane  1.0.4 - 4.0.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of exec-sh
    Depends on vulnerable versions of watch
    node_modules/sane
      jest-haste-map  16.1.0-alpha.691b0e22 - 24.0.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
      Depends on vulnerable versions of sane
      node_modules/jest-haste-map
        jest-cli  12.1.1-alpha.2935e14d || 12.1.2-alpha.6230044c - 24.8.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-config
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-snapshot
        Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
        Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
        node_modules/jest-cli
          jest  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.4 || 23.4.0 - 23.6.0
          Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-cli
          node_modules/jest
            react-scripts  >=0.3.0-alpha
            Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
            Depends on vulnerable versions of jest
            Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-flexbugs-fixes
            Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-safe-parser
            Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
            Depends on vulnerable versions of terser-webpack-plugin
            Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
            node_modules/react-scripts
        jest-runner  21.0.0-alpha.1 - 22.4.4 || 23.4.0 - 23.6.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-config
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
        node_modules/jest-runner
        jest-runtime  12.1.1-alpha.2935e14d - 24.8.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-plugin-istanbul
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-config
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
        Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
        Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
        node_modules/jest-runtime
    watch  >=0.14.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of exec-sh
    node_modules/watch

minimist  <0.2.1 || >=1.0.0 <1.2.3
Prototype Pollution - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1179
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/minimist
node_modules/rc/node_modules/minimist
  mkdirp  0.4.1 - 0.5.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of minimist
  node_modules/mkdirp

postcss  7.0.0 - 8.2.9
Severity: moderate
Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1693
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@4.0.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/postcss
  autoprefixer  9.0.0 - 9.8.6
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/autoprefixer
  css-blank-pseudo  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/css-blank-pseudo
    postcss-preset-env  >=6.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-blank-pseudo
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-prefers-color-scheme
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-color-gray
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-double-position-gradients
    node_modules/postcss-preset-env
  css-declaration-sorter  4.0.0 - 5.1.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/css-declaration-sorter
    cssnano-preset-default  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.8
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-declaration-sorter
    Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano-util-raw-cache
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
    node_modules/cssnano-preset-default
  css-has-pseudo  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/css-has-pseudo
  css-prefers-color-scheme  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/css-prefers-color-scheme
  cssnano  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.1.1 - 4.1.11
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/cssnano
  cssnano-util-raw-cache  >=4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/cssnano-util-raw-cache
  postcss-attribute-case-insensitive  4.0.0 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-attribute-case-insensitive
  postcss-calc  6.0.2 - 7.0.5
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-calc
  postcss-color-functional-notation  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-functional-notation
  postcss-color-gray  >=5.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-gray
  postcss-color-hex-alpha  4.0.0 - 6.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-hex-alpha
  postcss-color-mod-function  >=3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-mod-function
  postcss-color-rebeccapurple  >=4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-color-rebeccapurple
  postcss-colormin  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2 - 4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-colormin
  postcss-convert-values  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-convert-values
  postcss-custom-media  7.0.0 - 7.0.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-custom-media
  postcss-custom-properties  8.0.0 - 10.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-custom-properties
  postcss-custom-selectors  5.0.0 - 5.1.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-custom-selectors
  postcss-dir-pseudo-class  >=5.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-dir-pseudo-class
  postcss-discard-comments  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-discard-comments
  postcss-discard-duplicates  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-discard-duplicates
  postcss-discard-empty  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-discard-empty
  postcss-discard-overridden  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-discard-overridden
  postcss-double-position-gradients  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-double-position-gradients
  postcss-env-function  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-env-function
  postcss-flexbugs-fixes  4.0.0 - 4.2.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-flexbugs-fixes
    react-scripts  >=0.3.0-alpha
    Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-flexbugs-fixes
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-safe-parser
    Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of terser-webpack-plugin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
    node_modules/react-scripts
  postcss-focus-visible  >=4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-focus-visible
  postcss-focus-within  >=3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-focus-within
  postcss-font-variant  4.0.0 - 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-font-variant
  postcss-gap-properties  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-gap-properties
  postcss-image-set-function  >=3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-image-set-function
  postcss-initial  3.0.0 - 3.0.4
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-initial
  postcss-lab-function  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-lab-function
  postcss-loader  3.0.0 - 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-loader
  postcss-logical  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-logical
  postcss-media-minmax  4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-media-minmax
  postcss-merge-longhand  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.6 - 4.0.11
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-merge-longhand
  postcss-merge-rules  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2 - 4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-merge-rules
  postcss-minify-font-values  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-minify-font-values
  postcss-minify-gradients  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-minify-gradients
  postcss-minify-params  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-minify-params
  postcss-minify-selectors  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-minify-selectors
  postcss-nesting  7.0.0 - 7.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-nesting
  postcss-normalize-charset  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-charset
  postcss-normalize-display-values  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-display-values
  postcss-normalize-positions  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-positions
  postcss-normalize-repeat-style  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-repeat-style
  postcss-normalize-string  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-string
  postcss-normalize-timing-functions  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-timing-functions
  postcss-normalize-unicode  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-unicode
  postcss-normalize-url  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-url
  postcss-normalize-whitespace  <=4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-normalize-whitespace
  postcss-ordered-values  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.1.1 - 4.1.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-ordered-values
  postcss-overflow-shorthand  >=2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-overflow-shorthand
  postcss-page-break  2.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-page-break
  postcss-place  >=4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-place
  postcss-pseudo-class-any-link  >=6.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-pseudo-class-any-link
  postcss-reduce-initial  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.2 - 4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-reduce-initial
  postcss-reduce-transforms  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-reduce-transforms
  postcss-replace-overflow-wrap  3.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-replace-overflow-wrap
  postcss-safe-parser  4.0.0 - 4.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-safe-parser
  postcss-selector-matches  >=4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-selector-matches
  postcss-selector-not  4.0.0 - 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-selector-not
  postcss-svgo  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-svgo
  postcss-unique-selectors  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/postcss-unique-selectors
  stylehacks  4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9 - 4.0.0-rc.2 || 4.0.1 - 4.0.3
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/stylehacks

serialize-javascript  <=3.0.0
Severity: high
Cross-Site Scripting - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1426
Remote Code Execution - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1548
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@4.0.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/serialize-javascript
  terser-webpack-plugin  <=1.4.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of serialize-javascript
  node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin
    react-scripts  >=0.3.0-alpha
    Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-flexbugs-fixes
    Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-safe-parser
    Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of terser-webpack-plugin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
    node_modules/react-scripts

tar  <2.2.2 || >=3.0.0 <4.4.2
Severity: high
Arbitrary File Overwrite - https://npmjs.com/advisories/803
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/tar

yargs-parser  <=13.1.1 || 14.0.0 - 15.0.0 || 16.0.0 - 18.1.1
Prototype Pollution - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1500
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@4.0.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/yargs-parser
node_modules/yargs-parser
  yargs  4.0.0-alpha1 - 12.0.5 || 14.1.0 || 15.0.0 - 15.2.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs-parser
  node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/yargs
  node_modules/yargs
    jest-cli  12.1.1-alpha.2935e14d || 12.1.2-alpha.6230044c - 24.8.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-config
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-snapshot
    Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
    Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
    node_modules/jest-cli
      jest  18.5.0-alpha.7da3df39 - 22.4.4 || 23.4.0 - 23.6.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-cli
      node_modules/jest
        react-scripts  >=0.3.0-alpha
        Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-jest
        Depends on vulnerable versions of jest
        Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-flexbugs-fixes
        Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-safe-parser
        Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
        Depends on vulnerable versions of terser-webpack-plugin
        Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
        node_modules/react-scripts
    Depends on vulnerable versions of babel-plugin-istanbul
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-config
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-haste-map
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-message-util
    Depends on vulnerable versions of jest-util
    Depends on vulnerable versions of micromatch
    Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
    node_modules/jest-runtime
    webpack-dev-server  2.0.0-beta - 3.10.3
    Depends on vulnerable versions of yargs
    node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/webpack-dev-server

105 vulnerabilities (24 low, 71 moderate, 10 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force```
````

Comment: Similar question and answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67501746/postcss-7-0-0-8-2-9-severity-moderate-regular-expression-denial-of-service/67588637#67588637

Answer (score 1):

> See: https://github.com/postcss/postcss/issues/1574
>
> React-Scripts relies on v7.x of postcss, and v7 maintainer indicated no fix for v7.x >branch as it is no longer being supported.

from [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/n9txyv/npm_audit_fix_force_doesnt_resolve_the/)

In short : You can't get rid of these warnings currently but they shouldn't interfer with your development.

Answer (score -2):

this issue fixed by running below command:
yarn install
yarn start

for  reference: https://github.com/ossn/fixme/issues/53